# Matching codes to a database

Tags: database, redirect, input

I apologize in advance if it doesn't make sense. I am needing help for a school project.

Is there a way to have a code search a database based on an inputed value? If the inputed value matches a single phrase in the database it will then send the user to another page, but if it doesn't match a warning message would appear. But then after a code is matched to a value in a database make it to where that code could not be used again?

For those asking for more details here is the best I can describe it. Basically what I am wanting to do is put together a program that works in a similar way to gift card redeemers you can find on Amazon but instead of redeeming for money the code redirects the person to another webpage with exclusive content.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could store one-time passwords in a table. When the user enters one of the one-time password, he (= his/her web page) gets the OK to continue, and the one-time password is deleted from the table.

Another approach would be a second table which registers, that a given IP address has used the one-time password. This would allow other users with different IP addresses to login.